# Вопрос такой: почему строки "fr.add(pan);" и "pan.add(A);" не проходят проверку и являются по мнению программы неверными?

Tags: java, swing

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class frame{
            JFrame fr = new JFrame("title");
            JButton A = new JButton("asd");
            JPanel pan = new JPanel();
            fr.add(pan);
            pan.add(A);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что у классов JFrame и JPanel нет метода add().

Comment: @Fleckinger, у них у обоих есть такой метод, унаследованный из [`java.awt.Component::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методы не могут вызываться таким образом при определении переменных.  Они должны вызываться из конструктора / другого метода / блока инициализации:

```java
class frame {
    JFrame fr = new JFrame("title");
    JButton A = new JButton("asd");
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    frame() { // конструктор
        fr.add(pan);
        pan.add(A);
    }
}
```

```java
class frame {
    JFrame fr = new JFrame("title");
    JButton A = new JButton("asd");
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    { // блок инициализации
        fr.add(pan);
        pan.add(A);
    }
}
```